# Insert value into row in linq vb by calling record

Tags: vb.net, linq, insert

I have a LINQ VB.NET project.  I have a table "User".  I enter all the user details into the table.  This includes and email address.  I have a method which randomly generates a password.  I have another method which calls an email address, based on what has been entered in a text box, and sends the password to that email address.  My problem is that I can't figure out how to insert the newly generated password into the row belonging to the email address I have just called.  The text box that the email address is entered into is "txtEmail".  It can be assumed that the entry a "User" has already been completed, minus the password.  The following method generates the password:

```
Public Function GeneratePassword() As String

    'String variables tells how many characters password will contain.
    Dim PasswordLength As Int16 = "12"

    'Empty string will hold randomly generated password
    Dim NewPassword As String = ""

    'Characters allowed in this new password
    Dim allowedChars As String = ""
    allowedChars = "1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0"
    allowedChars += "A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P,Q,R,S,T,U,V,W,X,Y,Z,"
    allowedChars += "a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p,q,r,s,t,u,v,w,x,y,z,"

    'Declare array to house each character generated from allowed list of characters
    Dim sep As Char() = {","c}
    Dim arr As String() = allowedChars.Split(sep)

    Dim IDString As String = ""
    Dim temp As String = ""

    'utilize the "random" class
    Dim rand As New Random()

    'loop through the character generation process until PasswordLength is met
    For i As Integer = 0 To Convert.ToInt32(PasswordLength) - 1
        temp = arr(rand.[Next](0, arr.Length))
        IDString += temp

        NewPassword = IDString
    Next

    'places new password in variable
    Return NewPassword
End Function
```

Following on from that the following method fetches the email address from the database, calls the "GeneratePassword" method and emails the password to the user.  It does not save the password to the database, which is the problem I have.

```
Protected Sub btnPassword_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnPassword.Click
    If True Then

        'establish connection with database
        Dim db As New OrionDataClassesDataContext()

        'initialise global variabel to take email string entered in text box
        GlobalVariables.SearchUserEmail = txtEmailAddress.Text

        'initialise global variable to hold email address retrieved from database
        GlobalVariables.CurrentEmailAddress = (From u In db.Users
                                               Where u.Email = SearchUserEmail
                                               Select u.Email).FirstOrDefault

        'calls generatepassword method
        Dim stNewPassword As String = GeneratePassword()


        'create new mailmessage to construct and sendemail
        Dim Mail As New MailMessage
        Try
            Mail.Subject = "Your Password Has Been Reset"

            'gets email address from database when user enters it
            Mail.To.Add(GlobalVariables.CurrentEmailAddress)
            'address for email to be sent from
            Mail.From = New MailAddress("XXX@XXXX.com")

            Mail.Body = "Your new pasword is:  " + stNewPassword + ".  Please keep this safe."

            'define smpt server to be used
            Dim SMTP As New SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com")
            SMTP.EnableSsl = True

            'authenticate connection with smpt server and email address
            SMTP.Credentials = New System.Net.NetworkCredential("XXXX@XXX.com", "XXXXX")

            SMTP.Port = 587

            SMTP.Send(Mail)

            'alert when message is sent correctly
            MsgBox("Email sent successfully!")
            txtEmailAddress.Text = ""

        Catch ex As Exception
            'displays error message when email is not sent
            MsgBox("Email not sent - Check address")
            txtEmailAddress.Text = ""
        End Try


    End If
End Sub
```

I have been playing around with a few scenarios but I always seem to end up just trying to create a brand new row entry, which is not what I want to do.  Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Few comments. Do yourself a favour and don't work with global mutable variables. You don't tell where the password is stored. Is it a property of email address? Or is it a separate entity object belonging to email? If so, what type? You don't show the code where you assign the password to anything or how you save it. As yet, it is not clear why you can't seem to discern between update and insert. Please **edit your post** to clarify.

Comment: The password is ultimately stored in the database in the "User" table as an entity along with email, forename, surname and a few other values.  It is of type int.  To clairify I wish to insert the value of the new password into the database, to coincide with the record I will pull from the email address.  The password is firstly generated from the "GeneratePassword" method which places the password into a string DIM called "newpassword".

Comment: When the GeneratePassword method is called the new password is generated and held in "stNewPassword".  That is the intention anyway.  Coding newbie here so apologies for any inconsistency in what I am writing.

Comment: Again, please **edit your post**. Comments are easily overlooked. And: code says more than 1000 words. Words are open to misinterpretation and only add confusion.

Comment: I have edited the question to be much more complete.

Comment: Don't see any record being created or saved. You password generator has no bearing on the question, it's just noise.